# DefaultAuthenticateScheme Is Ignored and Controller Returns Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, authorization

I use JWT Bearer Authentication and set it up as the default as follows:

```
// Authentication setup
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        ...
    });
```

And the following is what I have to use the authorization on my controller:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and I have to use the following instead:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase {
    ...
}
```

Can someone explain me how I can avoid adding the AuthenticationScheme to each controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching, this was actually quite easy. The only thing you need to do is to switch up the pipeline to the following:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

It is important to have `UseAuthentication` **before** `UseAuthorization`.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness in answering your own question.  This was exactly my problem and solution.